# Symfony2 objects

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-query

I am having problem in getting data from doctrine object. When I use `findOne(id)` and try to access any variable like `$result->getVariable()` it works fine. But as soon as I use doctrine query builder and add some conditions, it says

```
Attempted to call method "getVariable" on class "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder....
```

My Code is

```
foreach ($Ids as $Id) {
            $result = $em->createQueryBuilder()->select("s")
                ->from("Entity", "s")
                ->where('s.id = :s_id')
                ->setParameters(array('s_id'=>$Id));
     if($category)
     {

        $result->innerJoin('s.cat','c');
        $result->where("c.primaryClassification =   :category");
        result->setParameter('category',$category);
    }

}
```

The Code which is working is

```
foreach ($Ids as $Id) {
$em->getRepository("Entity")->findOneById($Id);
}
```

I think it is the difference in data returned because of different types of methods used.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the QueryBuilder is only for that, to build querys (BA-DUM-TSS).
What you need is to execute the query after you build it and set the parameter correctly for a `=`:

```
foreach ($Ids as $Id) {
    $query[] = $em->createQueryBuilder()->select("s")
        ->from("Entity", "s")
        ->where('s.id = :s_id')
        ->setParameter('s_id', $Id))
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

also if you are looking for an array of data, is **BEST** if you use the IN statement without the `foreach` and pass the array directly to the `setParameter`:

```
$result = $em->createQueryBuilder()->select("s")
    ->from("Entity", "s")
    ->where('s.id IN (:s_id)')
    ->setParameter('s_id', $Ids)
    ->getQuery
    ->getResult();
```

If you need more info on the query builder [check the docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html).

Comment: I would use `setParameter` (as `setParameters` need an array) and I would not use `array_values` as passing direclty the array is fine.

Comment: Second approach is still the best, you should also highlight that practice ;)

Comment: Thanks, now the answer is better worded.

Comment: Another alternative is like `$queryBuilder = $em->getQuerBuilder(); $result = $queryBuilder...... ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->in('s.id', ':ids'))->setParameter('ids', $ids)` rather than building the expression directly.

Comment: Ok. Your query is working thanks for that. Now I want to add an if condition in my query. I have updated my question for that. Sorry i did not posted initially in my question.